# Set SPNavigationNode to open in a new window using PowerShell in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, powershell

Based off of several blog posts I attempted the code below:

```
$n1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode" -ArgumentList "People", "http://myURL", $true
$n1.properties["Target"] = "_blank"
$n1.Update()
```

This results in the error below with line 24 referencing the 2nd line of the code above.

> Cannot index into a null array. At
>   Z:\myscripts\SearchDropdownMenuSetup.ps1:24 char:5
>   +     $n1.properties["Target"] = "_blank"
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Is there any reason why I couldn't do this logic in PowerShell?

Comment: Can you post a link to one of the blogs? There really isn't a reason that wouldn't work in PowerShell, unless the SPNavigationNode class uses the HttpContext internally. From PowerShell the HttpContext will be blank.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was resolved by adding the node to the SPWeb before updating the property:

**Correct**

```
$n1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode" -ArgumentList "People", "http://myURL1", $true
$spWeb.Navigation.SearchNav.AddAsLast($n1)
$n1.properties["Target"] = "_blank"
$n1.Update()
```

**Incorrect**

```
$n1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode" -ArgumentList "People", "http://myURL1", $true
$n1.properties["Target"] = "_blank"
$n1.Update()
$spWeb.Navigation.SearchNav.AddAsLast($n1)
```